# Convert a date to 24 Hr format in vb.net using DateTime.TryParseExact()

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime, date-formatting

```
If DateTime.TryParseExact(sDate, sDateFormat, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, dReturnDate) = True Then
       Return True   
else
      Return False
End If
```

---

My date is "23/02/2016 17:00:05"

But after converting it is changed to "23/02/2016 05:00:05 PM"

Any way to solve this??

Comment: "it is changed to "23/02/2016 05:00:05 PM" How do you check that? From the debugger? from printing?

Comment: it is changed when i am debugging.

Comment: you don't need that `= True`

Comment: @san797 then it may just the display in the Visual Studio. The actual value is safe. No worries. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just do this -

```
var date = dReturnDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this thread should be outdated already, yet I tried to answer if it might help anyone who visit this thread later on.
I assume that you were viewing it from debugging.

Firstly, the value for **DateTime** datatype were stored as the number of ticking, which start since midnight of January 1st, 0001. What you were seeing while debugging was the representation of it, displayed in standard format.

I would suggest something like this if you wanted to see it in any format that you want.

You could first convert the **DateTime** into any presentation you want by converting to string.

```
Console.WriteLine(dReturnDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
```

Or you could achieve it by custom date and time formatting.

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", dReturnDate)
```